# Sending data to server with AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I need to update a table with new values in MySQL when an image is clicked.

```
$("#image1").click(function(){
```

Here's an example of the query:

```
mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE photos SET rating='$ratingnew1' WHERE link='$img1link'");
```

How do I execute that query only when the image is clicked?

Comment: Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: You can simply make an ajax call on click of this `image1` element to your server side method and post appropriate data to it..

Comment: Not directly. JS runs on the client, PHP runs on the server. At most JS can do an ajax call to the server and have the php executed that way.

Comment: @MarcB While looking at the title I think using AJAX is what he means indeed.

Comment: The problem is, I have no idea how to use AJAX exactly...

Comment: Here is a tutorial on [PHP with jQuery AJAX](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html). Work through that and you should start to understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#image1").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "update.php", 
         data: {img1link : 'image link', ratingnew1: 'rating'});
});
```

and then the update.php file

```
<?php
mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE photos SET rating='$ratingnew1' WHERE link='$img1link'")
?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.
You're missing critical pieces on the PHP side.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact your code must contain 2 parts: client side (JQuery) and server side (PHP). The JQuery code can be can be

```
$(document).ready({
    $("#image1").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "update.php", 
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                img1link : 'image link', 
                ratingnew1: 'new rating'
            },
            succsess: function(data){
                //some action
            }
        });
    });
});
```

here in `data` block you have to declare the variable which will be sent by `POST` action (as the `type` of the request is `POST`). For more possible settings and potions please see the [JQuery.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

For server side (in this particular example update.php) you can use the following code:

```
<?php
$data['img1link'] = '';
$data['ratingnew1'] = '';
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
    if(array_key_exists($key, $_POST))
        $data[$key] = $_POST[$key];
}

if($data['img1link'] != '')
    mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE photos SET rating='".mysqli_real_escape_string($data['ratingnew1'])."' WHERE link='".mysqli_real_escape_string($data['ratingnew1'])."'");
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.
You're missing critical pieces on the PHP side.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#image1").click(function(){
    $.post("update.php",{img1link : this.src});//here You send POST request to the server with post data img1link = src tag value of image
});
```

update.php

```
//and here You receive data $_POST['img1link']
    if(!empty($_POST)) {
       mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE photos SET rating=rating+1 WHERE link='".$_POST['img1link']."'")
    }
```